# Did anyone else hear Franz Liszt's Transcendental Etude no 12 (Chasse-Neige) in Frozen II?

Tags: music, disney, music-identification, frozen, frozen-ii

I was watching Frozen II at the cinemas today, and I was listening to some of the background music, and I'm pretty sure that I heard Franz Liszt's 12th Transcendental Etude in some of it. It was especially prominent in the scene where
(SPOILER)

> Elsa was putting out the magical fire in the forest with her ice powers

but I can't find the scene online in order to confirm my thoughts yet. If anyone could be able to help it would be appreciated.

Transcendental Etude 12:

Comment: This would be much more suited at Music stack exchange, rather than here

Comment: @Yasskier But it doesn't seem to be off-topic here.

Comment: @Randal'Thor Still, my guess is that it will be **more likely answered** on the Music Se than here.

Comment: @Yasskier thank you, I've reposted it there